# Flutter websocket working in local web but not in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm doing some tests with web_socket_channel Flutter plugin and I've noticed a very strange behavior. I've implemented flutter-dev's example, just changing the socket kind to HtmlWebSocketChannel in order to make it work in web builds. If I compile my app with flutter build web --release and later I expose it with a local webserver, it works perfectly fine. Same happens if I execute it in debug mode.

Comment: Hi Viral Lathiya, Can you post the error you see in the console log if there is any. Also your title says it doesn't work in release mode but your description suggest it works. Can you double check your statement once again.?

Answer (score 1):

add network permission in mainfest.xml